# Android download file with webview

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have app's MainActivity like this, and this app can't download file with `webview`

Anybody knows how to fix the download problem?

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace REC
{
    [Activity(Label = "APPNAME", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/rec512", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]

public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    private WebView mWebView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        mWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        mWebView.Settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
        mWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        mWebView.LoadUrl("http://www.APPname.com");
        mWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //  mWebView.SetDownloadListener(new MyDownloadListener()



    }


    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

        // Perform any customizations on the request.
        // This version of WebClient always preauthenticates.
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        return request;
    }






    class MonkeyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        public override bool OnJsAlert(WebView view, string url, string message, JsResult result)
        {
            return base.OnJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        public override Boolean OnJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
        {
            return base.OnJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        public override Boolean OnJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result)
        {
            return base.OnJsPrompt(view, url, message, defaultValue, result);
        }
    }

    public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && mWebView.CanGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.GoBack();

            return true;
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }





}
public class WebClient : WebViewClient
{

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        //return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    internal object GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not implement webview download listener,please refer to the following code :

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    WebView wv1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        wv1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
        wv1.SetDownloadListener(new MyDownloadListerner(this));
        wv1.LoadUrl("https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.2.html");
    }
    class MyDownloadListerner : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
    {
        Context cont;
        public MyDownloadListerner(Context context)
        {
            cont = context;
        }
        public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView,uri);
            cont.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: This method is start another browser to download, you can also create a new thread to download file at the `OnDownloadStart` function.**

screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i add the code , it works,but open a browser instead in webview,  is that possible to open it in webview?

Comment: @Mile Ma  do you know how to download files inside webview?

Comment: @Y2H I dont think you can do that. You create another post to ask this.

Comment: I'm having a "no activity to handle" error

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following code

```
public class WebViewFragment extends KaROFragment {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);
    try {
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}

public void downloadAndPrintDocument(WebView webView, String title) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

            //noinspection deprecation
            PrintDocumentAdapter printDocumentAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                printDocumentAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(title);

            String documentName = title;

            PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(documentName, printDocumentAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

            List<PrintJob> printJobs = printManager.getPrintJobs();

            printJobs.add(printJob);
        } else {
            //   mContext.showToast(mContext.getString(R.string.mytools_printing_not_supported), 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}